# How can I use RNN to predict 5 sequence numbers based on historical data?

Tags: machine-learning, python, lstm

Supposing I want to predict the next 5 sequences of numbers based on the historical data. my training set is as follow:

historical data: 3634 38 51 190 127 2422 568 5796 578 60 1935 -> next_value: 66

For the output, I want to predict the next 5 numbers in a sequence on the test set:

historical data: 2 1 208 1404 1134 413 135 40 -> next_values: 5 88 526 4551 97

The lengths of the sequences are different (min=5, max=29), and I've already trained some models, but I did not get good results.

I have some question:

1. Is this a sequence prediction problem?
2. How do I solve this problem with LSTM?

Comment: No problem considering this as a sequence. What's wrong with your current approach? You can predict y6, and then predict y7 based on y6, then y8 based on y7 etc. until you have predicted 5 values.

Comment: @CameronChandler Consider the historical data as product_id that a user has been bought, and I want to predict the next 5 product_id. Therefore, I want to predict based on all the sequences, not just the previous number. 
I built an LSTM model by padding the sequences, but the results were not good at all

Comment: Oh, in that case I would suggest that you are using the completely wrong algorithm. You may like to consider something like HMMs to predict categorical data, but LSTMs and other regression methods will be treating these product IDs as numeric values. i.e., product 1213 and 1214 are very similar but very different to 56, when in reality 1213 and 56 might be books and 1214 might be a toilet brush.

Comment: I would also say there might be another way to frame this problem that you may like to consider, like "If someone buys product A, what's the likelihood of them buying product B?" rather than considering some sort of time series. HMMs might not give great results either if you have over 1000 products and not too many customers (<1000 customers may be relatively useless even).